# Decomposability of Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

We know that, geometrically, the action of a linear operator $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is to take an element $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, scale it by some factor $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and rotate it through some angle $\theta$. What I'm wondering is the following -

Assuming $L$ is the matrix representation of an arbitrary $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ corresponding to the standard bases on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$, is it possible - in general - to decompose $L$ into two matrices: one scaling matrix and one rotation matrix?

If not, what are the sufficient and necessary conditions that would allow such a decomposition?

Comment: We know that?..

Comment: Your first paragraph is wrong. Think about this: If you were right, then why do we need $n\cdot m$ many parameters to describe such a linear operator, instead of just the two $\alpha$ and $\theta$

Comment: Interesting. If this isn't the case - what other (geometric) effects can a linear transformation have on an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: What you've said is partly true -- for any input vector $v$, there's a scalar $\alpha(v)$ and at least one rotation $R(v)$ with $T(v) = R(v) ( \alpha(v)v )$. The problem is that in general $\alpha$ and $R$ are not constant functions.

Comment: "What other effects?" Perhaps you should look at $\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1
}$ and  $\pmatrix{2 & 0 \\ 0 & -3}$, and when you fully understand what multiplication by those matrices does, come back and ask your question again.

Comment: First of all, your description applies specifically to $\Bbb R^2$, not $\Bbb R^n$ for arbitrary $n$. But even then, as John Hughes points out, it only applies to a certain subset of all linear transformations on the plane. Maybe you got the idea from a video describing multiplication of complex numbers?